# $T$ is measurable if, and only if, $\sigma(T) \subset \mathscr{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let Let $(X, \mathscr{A})$ and $\left(X^{\prime}, \mathscr{A}^{\prime}\right)$ be measurable spaces and $T: X \rightarrow X^{\prime}$. Show that $T$ is measurable if, and only if, $\sigma(T) \subset \mathscr{A}$.

---

My problem is showing from right to left. Assume that $\sigma(T^{-1}(\mathscr{A}')) \subseteq \mathscr{A}$. I actually want to conclude that this implies $T^{-1}(\mathscr{A}') \subseteq \mathscr{A}$. Which result (theorem, lemma etc.) makes this conclusion possible?.

This is have $\sigma$ is defined in the above
[image]

Comment: $\sigma(H)\supseteq H$ by definition.

Comment: Which definition? @Gae.S.

Comment: Of $\sigma(H)$ (for $H$ a family of subsets, not for a random variable)

Comment: @Gae.S. This is not have it is defined.

Comment: Please see the picture in my post.

Comment: @Gae.S. In that definition it does not say anything about $T^{-1}\left(\mathscr{A}^{\prime}\right)$ being contained in $\sigma(T^{-1}\left(\mathscr{A}^{\prime}\right))$?

Comment: I am referring to the definition of he $\sigma$ that is on the RHS of (7.4) (which is a different $\sigma$ from the one that is on the LHS).

Comment: It just say it is the smallest such that it is measurable.

Comment: @Gae.S. Do not understand how it is different. The one is defined as the other.